# In Joomla, jQuery code has single quote

Tags: jquery, joomla

I am adding some jquery code in default.php file in a component through addScriptDeclaration().

But I am not sure what is the correct format, since the code includes single quote, which will be confusing, how do i escape the single quote or replace it?

Code below:

```
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
$document = JFactory::getDocument();

   // Add Javascript
$script = 'jQuery(\'#atetimepicker\').datetimepicker();';
$script2 = 'jQuery(\'#datetimepicker\').datetimepicker({value:\'\',step:30});';
$document->addScriptDeclaration($script);
$document->addScriptDeclaration($script2);
```

Original jquery code

```
jQuery('#atetimepicker').datetimepicker();
jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({value:'',step:30});
```

Comment: Did you find my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap the whole string in double quotes instead:

```
$script = "jQuery('#atetimepicker').datetimepicker();";
```

If you use double quotes, single quotes don't need to be escaped and vice versa.

If your string contains both single and double quotes, then I recommend wrapping the string in the least commonly used one and then you'll have to escape the other with `\`.